# How to pass-by-reference a List of Tuples to multiple threads in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I am building a client/Bank erlang project and I wish to pass a List of tuples to various threads(ProcessIDs) so that whenever a thread changes some values in the List, other threads/processes also work on the same copy of the list.

This is required as I wish the customer threads to do some calculation and deduct the balance from the bank.
By now, I am able to create a process for all banks and customers and customers are able to call the bank process and deduct the money, but this deduction is only happening in the copy of bank list that the customer process has. 
How can I have a universal/global copy or Pass-by-reference copy of the List of tuples so it can be mutually worked upon by different processes.

```
Pid = spawn(customer, bazCust, [Name, Loan]),
T = {Name, Pid, Loan},
Pid ! {self(), Name, Loan, Pid, BankPidList},
get_feedback(),
```

The BankPidList I am using above looks like this:

```
[{rbc,<0.2067.0>,800},{bmo,<0.2068.0>,700},{ing,<0.2069.0>,200},0]
```

I am quite new to Erlang (just 4 days) so there could be some art which I am not using very efficiently but I just need to have the functionality done irresective of the efficiency for now.

Comment: have you seen ETS (Erlang Term Storage)? there is no global in Erlang. I think you have to use an ETS table.

Comment: Haven't yet learnt about it. I will look at this if an ETS table can solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not getting too complex with the language, I completed my project by constructing a bank module and passing its process Ids to all other customers. The customers make changes to this processId(by sending message/mail via

```
PID!{IDENTIFIER,{parameters}}
```

instead of making changes to its own local copy. 
You can make your work easier by registering the processIds with the name of the module(or some specific name)

```
register(Name, Pid)
```

but for beginners like me, it gives many errors when you re-run the module(don't know why but the solution is to terminate the process and compile again). Again, I am a beginner in Erlang and might miss correct language-specific terminology.
Following is a link to my code 
https://github.com/NitinNanda/Scalable-Message-Passing-Bank-Client.git

Answer (score 3):

To all you bank/client people who have been flooding SO recently with questions:

1. In erlang the term `thread` does not exist.  They are called `processes`.  The underlying implementation is irrelevant.  Please do not say `thread` again in any of your posts about erlang.
2. Your teacher sucks.  If you actually want to learn erlang, buy `Programming Erlang`, read it, and do all the exercises.

> I am building a client/Bank erlang project and I wish to pass a List
>   of tuples to various threads(ProcessIDs) so that whenever a thread
>   changes some values in the List, other threads/processes also work on
>   the same copy of the list.

Have you covered OTP gen_servers yet?  A gen_server sets up a client-server relationship, where clients can ask the gen_server for the current value of a list.  Clients can also change the value of the list.  The gen_server enters a recursive loop, like this:

```
loop(State) ->
    receive
        {get_state} -> 
            %send State to client
            loop(State);
        {set_state, 10} ->  
            loop([10|NewState])
    end
end
```

When you start the gen_server, the State can be a list, e.g. `[]`, or `[1, 2, 3]`. The clients can send messages to the server to either get the value of the State variable or set the State variable.

> I am quite new to Erlang (just 4 days)

Then you will not be able to write the program: all you can do is ask other people to write the code for you.  What good is that? Why did your teacher believe that after 4 days of learning erlang that you could write a multiprocess program?

> By now, I am able to create a process for all banks and customers and
>   customers are able to call the bank process and deduct the money, but
>   this deduction is only happening in the copy of bank list that the
>   customer process has. How can I have a universal/global copy or
>   Pass-by-reference copy of the List of tuples so it can be mutually
>   worked upon by different processes.

The main principle of erlang (and all other functional languages) is that no process can change the data that another process is working on.  All you can do is send a copy of data to another process.  If a bank process needs to know how much is in a customer account, then it can keep track of the balance in a recursive loop:

```
init(Deposit) ->
    loop(Deposit).

loop(Balance) ->
    receive
        {From, {deduct, Amount}} ->
            case Balance >= Amount of
               true -> 
                   From ! whatever,
                   bank(Balance - Amount);

               _    -> 
                   From ! whatever
                   bank(Balance)
            end
    end.
```

You could also add a `deposit` message to the receive clause:

```
    {From, {deposit, Amount}} ->
        From ! whatever,
        bank(Balance + Amount)
```

`Balance` can also be a list of tuples where each tuple is a customer account, with a more appropriate variable name, say `Balances`.  To find a customer in the `Balances` list, you can use `lists:keyfind()`; to delete the old balance, you can use `lists:keydelete()`, and to add a new balance to the list, you can do:  `[{Pid, NewBalance} | Balances]`.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer and suggestions about gen_server. Will probably need to use this to complete my project. I also needed the lists: functions for additions and deletions. Will update the post once I am able to do this.